# Can't get SDK working

Tags: android

so i'm already struggling the whole day to get the android sdk running, but it still doesn't work.

- I have the newest JDK installed and working (version 1.8.0_131)
- Android SDK downloaded, unzipped and placed the "tools" folder into the created "C:\android-sdk" folder
- Not a single .bat file works in the tools folder, so I created all kind of environment variables
- JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
- JDK_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%
- JRE_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%\jre
- CLASSPATH : .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
- PATH      : your-unique-entries;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
- still not a single .bat works in the tools folder.

All explanations or tutorials seems to be outdated or not working.
I'm actually  so frustrated that I don't want to learn Android development anymore >_<

Comment: can you please provide the screenshot of the point where you actually came to know that its your sdk which is not working?

Comment: Can't provide screenshot because the I don't see any output of the batch files (windows instantly closes). And I also don't find any references to any android related stuff in my computer beside the files i downloaded